# I need to refresh SwiftUI View, when @propertyWrapper is passed into

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have an example struct:

```
public struct Axis: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    public var name: String
    public var description: String {
        return "Axis: \"\(name)\""
    }
}
```

And property wrapper to make some operations on `[Axis]` struct.

```
@propertyWrapper
struct WrappedAxes {
    var wrappedValue: [Axis] {
        // This is just example, in real world it's much more complicated.    
        didSet {
            for index in wrappedValue.indices {
                var elems = Array(wrappedValue[index].name.split(separator: " "))
                if elems.count>1 {
                    elems.removeLast()
                }
                let new = elems.reduce(into:"", {$0 += "\($1) "})
                wrappedValue[index].name = new+("\(Date())")
}   }   }   }
```

And I try to add, insert and remove `Axes` in SwiftUI View:

```
public struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var axes: [Axis]
    public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(axes.indices, id:\.self) {index in
                HStack {
                    TextField("", text: $axes[index].name)
                    Button("Delete", action: {deleteAxis(index)})
                    Button("Insert", action: {insertAxis(index)})
                }
            }
            Button("Add", action: addAxis)
        }
    }
    
    var addAxis: () -> Void {
        return {
            axes.append(Axis(name: "New"))
            print (axes)
        }
    }
    
    var deleteAxis: (_:Int)->Void {
        return {
            if  $0 < axes.count {
                axes.remove(at: $0)
            }
            print (axes)
        }
    }
    
    var insertAxis: (_:Int)->Void {
        return {
            if  $0 < axes.count {
                axes.insert(Axis(name: "Inserted"), at: $0)
            }
            print (axes)
        }
    }
    
    public init (axes: Binding<[Axis]>) {
        self._axes = axes
    }
}
```

As far, as `print (axes)` shows changes are made, View never updates. I made very small App to test in which I call `ContentView`:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    @WrappedAxes var axes = [Axis(name: "FirstOne")]

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let contentView = ContentView(
            axes: Binding (
                get: {self.axes},
                set: { [self] in axes = $0}))
    .... // No fancy stuff
```

I'm open for all critique of code itself, and help: how to push this view (and all possible future subviews) to update when `axes` changed?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that @Binding is for nested Views. When you want to make changes in a SwiftUI view, you have to use the @State instead in the one where the action starts. Plus, you don't need to set an initialiser this way. You can set your value like this, inside an ObservableObject to handle your logic:

```
struct Axis {

  var name: String
  var description: String {
    return "Axis: \"\(name)\""
  }
}

final class AxisViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Published var axes: [Axis] = [Axis(name: "First")]

  init() { handleAxes() }

  func addAxis() {
    axes.append(Axis(name: "New"))
    handleAxes()
  }

  func insertAxis(at index: Int) {
    axes.insert(Axis(name: "Inserted"), at: index)
    handleAxes()
  }

  func handleAxes() {
    for index in axes.indices {
      var elems = Array(axes[index].name.split(separator: " "))
      if elems.count > 1 {
        elems.removeLast()
      }
      let new = elems.reduce(into:"", { $0 += "\($1) " })
      axes[index].name = new + ("\(Date())")
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject var viewModel = AxisViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(viewModel.axes.indices, id:\.self) { index in

        HStack {
          TextField("", text: $viewModel.axes[index].name)
          Button("Insert", action: { viewModel.insertAxis(at: index) })
        }
      }

      Button("Add", action: viewModel.addAxis)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, that's simple. But does [Axes] will change outside of View, in AppDelegate? It will be copy of [Axes] in View I think, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Your '@State var axes' will make changes everywhere it is called. This is why you use @Binding in nested views.

Comment: Why would you want to set axes in AppDelegate?

Comment: They're defined there just for example. But they could be anywhere. I need UI to edit values, but not leave them just inside View.

Comment: You can create a viewModel using the ObservableObject protocol to hold you r'@State' values that can be used in any views. You can call with view model inside your SwiftUI view using the '@ObservedObject'.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved.

Comment: It doesn't work for `@WrappedAxes var axes = [Axis]`. No wrappers in wrappers, so I can't use `@Published @WrappedAxes var axes = [Axis]`

Comment: If I use @State var axes:[Axis], all stuff in wrapper is ignored. It's exactly what I want to avoid (It's why I made this wrapper, I need this stuff). As far I know it's a only way to set array's `didSet` — only in wrapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222494/discussion-between-roland-lariotte-and-lukasz).

Answer (score -1):

I made a new struct Axes:

```
public struct Axes {
    
    @WrappedAxes var _axes: [Axis]
          
    public subscript (index: Int) -> Axis {
        get { return _axes[index]}
        set { _axes[index] = newValue}
    }
    
    // and all needed functions and vars to simulate Array behaviour:

    public mutating func append(_ newElement: Axis )  {
        _axes.append(newElement)
    }
    
    public mutating func insert(_ newElement: Axis, at index: Int )  {
        _axes.insert(newElement, at: index)
    }

    public mutating func remove(at index: Int )  {
        _axes.remove(at: index)
    }
    
    ....
}
```

and put it into `@ObservalbeObject`:

```
public class Globals: ObservableObject {
            
    @Published public var axes: Axes
    ....
}
```

Then defined AxesView  as

```
public struct AxesView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var globals: Globals
    
    public var body: some View {

       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

That's all. For a while it works.